# Javascript Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, token

I have a PHP script (fetchData.php) that fetches some data and outputs it to a page.

```
<?php 
require 'config.php'; 
require 'jsonapiSDK.php';
$api = new JSONAPI($ip_address, $jsonapi_port, $username, $password, $salt);
$response = $api->call('BWMFunction');
echo(addslashes($response["success"].";")); 
?>
```

You can see the output here: http://justicecraft.net/worldmap/fetchData.php
I have another page that uses an XMLHttpRquest to get the response from fetchData.php
Here's the JavaScript for it. It's supposed to take the response, and eval() it (to create an array called BWMFunction) then pass that array to another function I have. The Illegal token error occurs when I try to eval() the response.

```
function fetchData() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            res = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(res);
            eval(res);
            generate(BWMFunction);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetchData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is my first time on StackOverflow, so any help would be appreciated. I have googled around for quite a while now, but none of the answers helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have invalid javascript returned from `fetchData.php` which is why the `eval` method crashes. Instead of `\"` in the output you should have simple `"`. I know strictly nothing about PHP but I am ready to bet some bucks that its the `addslashes` function which is causing the damage. So maybe you could try something along the lines of:

```
echo($response["success"].";");
```

Comment: Wow, so obvious, but it worked! it's ironic because I added the addslashes() because I was trying to get rid of a problem, but it must've been another problem entirely! Thanks!

Comment: @DrAgonmoray, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.